# How do I keep black areas black with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

When encoding GoPro videos with ffmpeg using

```
ffmpeg -i Goprovideo.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:-1,crop=1920:1080:0:362 Goprovideo-out.mp4
```

I noticed that the videos do not only get much smaller, but also in some cases do black areas lose intensity. So what was black is now grey. Not to an extreme, but slightly noticable.

How do I keep black areas black with ffmpeg?

Comment: Share the full console output. It sounds like a wrong color range scaling or tagging issue.

Comment: @Mulvya https://pastebin.com/Gg1iHwyn

Comment: As I though. The input is full range and nothing is done to expressly tag output as full. Add `-color_range 2` and check. If the player is compliant, this all that's needed. If not, we'll have to scale the range down.

Comment: @Mulvya How do you scale the range down for the colors to match in this case? I use the same player for both video files(potplayer) and it shows different colors. EDIT: Could it be that the colors match but downsampling from 2.7K to 1080p makes the images *seem* brighter?

Comment: @Gyan I already tried this, but it does exaclty the same, and I think this is just the whites, you can clearly tell the cange in dark scenes or complete black scenes. I don't think is a color thing. I'm using NvEnc